# Selecting columns with two levels (binary variables) from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select data fields that have only two values [0, 1]. My code works for one column, however it fails when I try to loop through many columns.

Here is the sample dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,2, size = (10)),
                    'b':np.random.randint(0,2, size = (10)),
                    'c':np.random.randint(0,6, size = (10)),
                   'd': ['x', 'y']*5
                  })
df
```

data looks like this:

```
df.to_dict()
{'a': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 1},
 'b': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 1},
 'c': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 0, 8: 4, 9: 3},
 'd': {0: 'x',
  1: 'y',
  2: 'x',
  3: 'y',
  4: 'x',
  5: 'y',
  6: 'x',
  7: 'y',
  8: 'x',
  9: 'y'}}
```

Columns 'a' and 'b' should be selected. 
The line below yields true, which is what I want.

```
list(set(df[mylist[0]])) == [0,1]
```

Why am I getting a keyError when I run this:

```
mylist = list(df.columns)

for i in mylist:
    if list(set(df[mylist.index(i)])) == [0,1]:
        print(i)
```

KeyError: 0

I'm trying to output list of columns names, that satisfy the IF condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,2, size = (10)),
                    'b':np.random.randint(0,2, size = (10)),
                    'c':np.random.randint(0,6, size = (10)),
                   'd': ['x', 'y']*5
                  })
df
```

---

Use [DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) + [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df.loc[:,df.isin([0,1]).all()]
```

or

```
df.loc[:,(df.eq(0)|df.eq(1)).all()]
```

Also you can use:

```
df[df.columns[df.isin([0,1]).all()]]
```

or:

```
df.T[df.isin([0,1]).all()].T
```

**Output:**

```
   a  b
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  0  1
3  0  1
4  1  1
5  0  1
6  1  0
7  1  1
8  0  1
9  0  0
```

get the columns:

```
[*df.loc[:,df.isin([0,1]).all()].columns]
#['a', 'b']
```

**to select by rows simply do:**

```
df[df.isin([0,1]).all(axis=1)]
```

> why don't work....

```
print(mylist)
#['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
mylist.index('a')
#returns 0
df[0]
#key error 0 because 0 not in list of columnas a,b,c,d...
```

Comment: I get this error: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match-- for the first option, the third seems to return the columns I want. Thanks. However what's causing my original code to fail?

Comment: Yes your code works, however I would like to understand what causes my original code to fail. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the solution to understand why it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using transpose and sum like below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 1},
 'b': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 1},
 'c': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 0, 8: 4, 9: 3},
 'd': {0: 'x',
  1: 'y',
  2: 'x',
  3: 'y',
  4: 'x',
  5: 'y',
  6: 'x',
  7: 'y',
  8: 'x',
  9: 'y'}})


## Solution
df.T[df.sum()==(df==1).sum()].T
```